# Convergence in Probability Example With Stock Prices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, finance

Why are sequences of random variables, instead of the sequential observed values of a single random variable, the objects of study in the topic of convergence in probability?

Extrapolating from [this](https://youtu.be/waaVawAdy9g?t=1624) example, would another example be a stock's price, where the sequential observed values of a single random variable represent the evolving stock price up to a certain number of observations, and each random variable in the sequence appends a new observed value?  The problem with this is the video seems to suggest that the sequence of random variables should represent a sequence of moving averages, whereas my assignments would require taking each random variable's expected value as a further step (which doesn't happen in the convergence formula, and it sounds in the video like each random variable just *is* an expected value).

What is the correct way to build this model?

Answer (score 1):

Stock price would be better modeled by a stochastic process. In simple terms, a stochastic process is a random element from the probability space $$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$$ to a subspace of functions, just like a random variable maps from from the probability space to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

See: http://katzman.staff.shef.ac.uk/MAS362/BChapter5Slides%20PRINTABLE.pdf